# Как получить доступ к сессии определенного пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть задача определить, находится ли пользователь на сайте или нет.
При входе на сайт у пользователя создается сессия.
Собственно и стоит задача: получить доступ к этой сессии через пользователя, но я не очень понимаю, как это можно сделать.
В качестве альтернативы, наверное, можно всякий раз при входе на сайт и выходе с него менять у пользователя значение is_active на True или False, но я подозреваю, что это не лучшая идея.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723052/how-to-get-the-list-of-the-authenticated-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете помещать ключ сессии в поле модели, унаследованной от AbstractUser через middleware, предварительно расширив ее. Сохранять пользователя, если ключ сессии отличается.

Пример из комментария не идеален, так как придется пройтись по всем пользователям/сессиям, а это лишние операции, если требуется сессия конкретного пользователя.

Менять is_active - плохая идея, т.к. получится, что когда пользователь залогинен - его учетка не активна. Крч, это все сломает)

Comment: Да, пример в комментарии может заслуживать внимания

Comment: Может лучше развернуть Channels и использовать WebSocket'ы?

Comment: С этим не работал, не скажу ничего по этому поводу